# If 'x' is real then $\frac{x^2-x+c}{x^2+x+2c}$ can take all real values if?

Tags: quadratics

the question asks for the interval in which c lies so that $\frac{x^2-x+c}{x^2+x+2c}$ gives all real values for all x belongs to R.

how to proceed in this problem?

Comment: Well... when would that ever *not* be real?  There's only one way that expression wouldn't be real.  When would that be.  For what values of c will that never happen?

Comment: What are you asking? Do you want $c$ such that the expression is defined for all real numbers? Or do you want $c$ such that the function is surjective onto $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $y = \frac{x^2-x+c}{x^2+x+2c} $ be a value taken by the given fraction. This gives 
\begin{equation*}
x^2(y-1) +x(y+1) +c(2y-1) = 0
\end{equation*}
should have a real root. Thus 
\begin{equation*}
(y+1)^2 -4c(y-1)(2y-1) \geq 0
\end{equation*}
and hence
\begin{equation*}
y^2(1-8c) + 2y(1+6c)+(1-4c) \geq 0
\end{equation*}
If the given expression takes all values, then the above should be true for all $y$. Thus we have 
\begin{equation*}
(1+6c)^2 - (1-8c)(1-4c) \leq 0
\end{equation*}
and $8c \leq 1$. The above expression simplifies to $24c+4c^2 \leq 0$ and hence $-6 \leq c \leq 0$. 
when $c=-6$, the graph is:[image] Clearly, $y=1$ is an asymptote and hence the expression misses the value 1. Again, the same phenomenon is observed when $c=0$. Thus the required range is $-6 < c < 0$
For negative values outside the range, the graph is [image] and for positive values of $c$, the graph is [image] and for values within the range, the graph is [image]

Comment: Using c = -6 as example. Then, the denominator becomes $x^2 + x – 12 = (x – 3)(x + 4)$. This means x must not be 3 or -4. The 1st graph clearly shows a jump at x = -4. Shouldn’t there be a jump at x = 3 also?

Comment: $x-3$ is a factor of the numerator as well when $c=-6$ and hence cancels out.

Comment: Even if the numerator and the denominator have the same common factor (and can be cancelled out), we still cannot ignore its presence.

Comment: Yes, but as x tends to 3, the limiting value is finite and hence we do not see the jump.

Comment: @Muralidharan Why do we need to check at $c=0$ and $c=-6$? What did we miss in previous steps so that we need to check at upper bound and lower bound of $c$?